# Flow Finish Location For Newly Created Record

Tags: visual-workflow, record

Has anyone successfully built a flow that creates a record then directs user to that newly created record? Trying to do this in Lightning with a VF page Action. 
This is my code so far:

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="NCSIIntensiveActivityCreate"
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Where exactly are you stuck?